# javascript assign value to an undefined variable

Tags: javascript, nashorn

I'm looking for a way to make it possible to assign value to undefined numbers in javascript. usually we write like this,

```
var a = {};a.b = {};a.b.c = 'hello world';
```

if there is any solution to make code like this possible?

```
var a={}; a.b.c='hello world';
```

Comment: `var a = {b: {c: 'hello world'}}` wouldn't cut it, I guess

Comment: How should JS know what type of structure `b` is? You can't do `let a; a.b=1` because of this.

Comment: Difficult to say what it is exactly you are looking to accomplish, but you can map the key and values to a `Map` and iterate through them, that way you preserve the order of operations.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, No. a.b needs to be assigned before you try to assign a.b.c a value.

The best way to accomplish the result you want is to use a Javascript object literal.

```
let a = {
  b: = {
    c: 'hello World'
    }
 };
```

This is easier to read and this is more the standard way of creating JS objects.
Keeping all that on one line isn't a great coding style. Adding some new lines makes it easier to read and easier to debug with breakpoints.

Here are some links to check out:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 1):

Not *exactly* what you are asking, but you can create a custom object that could be used like this.

```
function A(){
    this.b = {};
}

var a = new A();
a.b.c = "Hello World";
```

Comment: aren't you missing the this key word "this.b  = {}; " ?

Answer (score 0):

You kind of answered your own question.
Is there a way to assign value to an undefined variable? **WHY**?
A quick look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) of `undefined` tells you that `undefined` has the property attribute `Writable` set to `false`. So, simply put, you cannot.
Even if you could, how would the compiler know what is `b` in your case, until and unless you specify it?

Comment: I don't think OP wants to change the value of `undefined`. Seems like poor wording but what I get is that OP wants to have something like `var a={}; a.b.c='hello world';` and JS to somehow figure out `a.b` is also an object, without having to specify it.

Comment: I think the OP wants to understand "why" it cannot be done, as it cannot be done in JS based on the question. Not poor wording I guess, a valid question for someone new to JS and `undefined`

Comment: well, that's sort of what I mean. I chose to call it "poor wording" because it's not about changing the value of `undefined`. To us, this suggests doing something like `undefined = "fred"`, so you get `var a; console.log(a); //fred` (good old IE allowed it...). To OP it doesn't mean redefining `undefined` in every single instance, but in just this one where you do `a.b.c = "hello world"`. It's a clash of how OP and us understand the idea of `assign value to undefined`.